# Wordpress - adding a widget between the menu and content

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have just setup my first wordpress site and I need to be able to add slidedeck 2 in between my menu and content much like you see on alot of websites.

I already have the built in slider that the theme came with but I need to use slidedeck 2 for various reasons.

Here is a picture of what I mean and what I am looking to do: [explanation picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvBqa.jpg)

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Check your index page code. Take the code of widget & paste it in your `single.php` or `page.php` as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to open your home page file(may be index or page or template or header) and put below code when you want slidedeck 2:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( "[SlideDeck2 id=your_id]" ); ?>
```

Comment: This works but is there a way to have it appear on only the pages you want it to appear on?

Comment: for that you need to place it into condition like for home page, if(is_home()){ //shortcode }

Answer (score 0):

if you need a fully customizable slideshow i reccomend you [THIS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slideshow-jquery-image-gallery/) plugin.

With this plugin you can add slideshows inside pages or posts content with shortcodes like this [slideshow_deploy id='slide_id']

if you want to print your slideshow in some particular position, you can use this function:

```
echo do_shortcode('[slideshow_deploy id='321']');
```

use this code inside a page of your theme, ie. header.php or page.php or single.php or wherever you need it,